# Making a masked gradient for the top and bottom of a div

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

It's my first time posting a question so please excuse me if I am not doing it right. I am trying to create a mask gradient for both the top and bottom of my div. It seems I can only apply one mask gradient at a time. Does anyone know how I can do that?

```
<div className="inline-flex flex-nowrap gradient-mask-t-80">
  <div className="flex flex-col no-scrollbar animate-review-scroll gap-7 w-[360px] ml-7 mt-12 z-0">
    <div className="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5 mt-36 ">
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
      </div>
      <p className="text-taupe_gray text-sm">2 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Eric is pleasant and timely. He <br />
        reached on time, parcel is dry <br />
        even thought it's raining heavily. <br />
        Tracking number: ZL9T21 Thnx <br />
      </p>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div className="flex rounded-full bg-[#C1185A] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          J
        </div>
        <p className="font-bold text-black">Joanna Mohan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
      </div>
      <p className="text-taupe_gray text-sm">6 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Jerand Chua is a very efficient <br />
        delivery agent with Uparcel. Not <br />
        only fast but also meticulous. He <br />
        manage to send my parcels <br />
        XYKJZC promptly even thought I <br />
        label the boxes wrongly. Well <br />
        deserved a 5 star rating. He really <br />
        loves his job.
      </p>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div className="flex rounded-full bg-purple-500 items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          P
        </div>
        <p className="font-bold text-black">Peter Tan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
      </div>
      <p className="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Mr. Liu JunKang delivered my <br />
        durian speedily after picking up <br />
        the order. My durian still in tip top <br />
        condition upon receiving. <br />
        Appreciate for his great service.
      </p>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div className="flex rounded-full bg-[#5B6BC0] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p className="font-bold text-black">Agnes Mah</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
        <img src={star} />
      </div>
      <p className="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Tracking ZTKVAK, fast delivery. <br />
        My med from white coat came less <br />
        than 3 hours after consultation. <br />
        Thank you
      </p>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div className="flex rounded-full bg-[#502DA7] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p className="font-bold text-black">Ang Siaw She</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if there are other libraries that can help me with it. But I downloaded the gradient-mask plugin using NPM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified what the bottom gradient mask should be like, so I'll use a symmetrical version of the top mask as the bottom one.

You could consider using an [arbitrary property class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties) to apply a custom `mask-image` value:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="inline-flex flex-nowrap [mask-image:linear-gradient(0deg,transparent_0%,#000_20%,#000_80%,transparent_100%)]">
  <div class="flex flex-col no-scrollbar animate-review-scroll gap-7 w-[360px] ml-7 mt-12 z-0">
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5 mt-36 ">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">2 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Eric is pleasant and timely. He <br />
        reached on time, parcel is dry <br />
        even thought it's raining heavily. <br />
        Tracking number: ZL9T21 Thnx <br />
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#C1185A] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          J
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Joanna Mohan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">6 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Jerand Chua is a very efficient <br />
        delivery agent with Uparcel. Not <br />
        only fast but also meticulous. He <br />
        manage to send my parcels <br />
        XYKJZC promptly even thought I <br />
        label the boxes wrongly. Well <br />
        deserved a 5 star rating. He really <br />
        loves his job.
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-purple-500 items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          P
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Peter Tan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Mr. Liu JunKang delivered my <br />
        durian speedily after picking up <br />
        the order. My durian still in tip top <br />
        condition upon receiving. <br />
        Appreciate for his great service.
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#5B6BC0] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Agnes Mah</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Tracking ZTKVAK, fast delivery. <br />
        My med from white coat came less <br />
        than 3 hours after consultation. <br />
        Thank you
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#502DA7] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Ang Siaw She</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also consider using "vanilla" CSS:

```css
.foo {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0%, #000 20%, #000 80%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="inline-flex flex-nowrap foo">
  <div class="flex flex-col no-scrollbar animate-review-scroll gap-7 w-[360px] ml-7 mt-12 z-0">
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5 mt-36 ">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">2 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Eric is pleasant and timely. He <br />
        reached on time, parcel is dry <br />
        even thought it's raining heavily. <br />
        Tracking number: ZL9T21 Thnx <br />
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#C1185A] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          J
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Joanna Mohan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">6 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Jerand Chua is a very efficient <br />
        delivery agent with Uparcel. Not <br />
        only fast but also meticulous. He <br />
        manage to send my parcels <br />
        XYKJZC promptly even thought I <br />
        label the boxes wrongly. Well <br />
        deserved a 5 star rating. He really <br />
        loves his job.
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-purple-500 items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          P
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Peter Tan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Mr. Liu JunKang delivered my <br />
        durian speedily after picking up <br />
        the order. My durian still in tip top <br />
        condition upon receiving. <br />
        Appreciate for his great service.
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#5B6BC0] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Agnes Mah</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Tracking ZTKVAK, fast delivery. <br />
        My med from white coat came less <br />
        than 3 hours after consultation. <br />
        Thank you
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#502DA7] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Ang Siaw She</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also consider using a Tailwind plugin in many different ways. Here's a simple example of the aforementioned CSS as a [static utility class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-utilities):

```js
tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addUtilities }) => {
      addUtilities({
        '.foo': {
          maskImage: 'linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0%, #000 20%, #000 80%, transparent 100%)',
        }
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="inline-flex flex-nowrap foo">
  <div class="flex flex-col no-scrollbar animate-review-scroll gap-7 w-[360px] ml-7 mt-12 z-0">
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5 mt-36 ">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">2 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Eric is pleasant and timely. He <br />
        reached on time, parcel is dry <br />
        even thought it's raining heavily. <br />
        Tracking number: ZL9T21 Thnx <br />
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#C1185A] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          J
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Joanna Mohan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">6 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Jerand Chua is a very efficient <br />
        delivery agent with Uparcel. Not <br />
        only fast but also meticulous. He <br />
        manage to send my parcels <br />
        XYKJZC promptly even thought I <br />
        label the boxes wrongly. Well <br />
        deserved a 5 star rating. He really <br />
        loves his job.
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-purple-500 items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          P
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Peter Tan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Mr. Liu JunKang delivered my <br />
        durian speedily after picking up <br />
        the order. My durian still in tip top <br />
        condition upon receiving. <br />
        Appreciate for his great service.
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#5B6BC0] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Agnes Mah</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-xl font-inter gap-2 p-5 mx-5">
      <div class="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/16/16" />
      </div>
      <p class="text-taupe_gray text-sm">4 months ago</p>
      <p>
        Tracking ZTKVAK, fast delivery. <br />
        My med from white coat came less <br />
        than 3 hours after consultation. <br />
        Thank you
      </p>
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
        <div class="flex rounded-full bg-[#502DA7] items-center justify-center text-white font-bold w-[30px] h-[30px] ">
          A
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-black">Ang Siaw She</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```